# Android Travado ao chamar API

Tags: java, android-studio

Tenho esse **método** no **main**:

```
private String token () throws IOException {

    String login = this.login.getText().toString();
    String senha = this.senha.getText().toString();

    Login dados = new Login(login, senha);

    HttpService HttpService = new HttpService("https://www.acweb.net.br/api/orcamentos/login");

    String retorno = HttpService.execute(dados).toString();

    return retorno;

}
```

Que chama uma classe **HttpService** que estende **AsyncTask** a seguir:

```
package br.net.concertacell.classes;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HttpService extends AsyncTask<Login, Integer, String> {

    private String url;

    public HttpService (String _url) {

        this.url        =  _url;

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Login... parametros) {

        StringBuilder resposta = new StringBuilder();

        try {

            URL url = new URL(this.url);

            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            String json = new Gson().toJson(parametros);
            System.out.println("retorno: " + json);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.getOutputStream().write(json.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
            connection.connect();

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream());
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                resposta.append(scanner.next());
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return resposta.toString();
    }

}
```

O **problema**:

Da linha **System.out.println("retorno: " + json);**, tenho a seguinte resposta:

```
I/System.out: retorno: [{"id":0,"login":"Teste","senha":"Testando"}]
```

Ou seja, um **json**, que é o que a **API** espera.

Mas Quando passa ás linhas abaixo:

```
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.getOutputStream().write(json.getBytes("UTF-8"));
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
connection.connect();
```

então o sistema trava.

Há algo errado nesse código?

Tentei da forma abaixo e também dá o mesmo erro:

```
public String post(String json) throws IOException {

        URL url = new URL("https://www.acweb.net.br/api/orcamentos/login");

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(connection.getOutputStream());

        printStream.println(json);

        connection.connect();

        String jsonDeResposta = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream()).next();

        return jsonDeResposta;

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Login... parametros) {

        StringBuilder resposta = new StringBuilder();
        String json = new Gson().toJson(parametros);
        try {
            this.post(json);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return resposta.toString();
    }
```

Está me parecendo que é a forma de enviar o **JSON**:

```
[{"id":0,"login":"Teste","senha":"Testando"}]
```

Mas não tenho certeza!

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o problema esteja nessas linhas:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
```

Você chama o mesmo método duas vezes, com valores diferentes.